# marquee works on simulator but not on device

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

Hi  I had added marquee tag in my application which works well in android simulator but when I install it on device it is not working. On device it doesn't show me marquee.  Below is my code for marquee.

```
<marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left">Welcome To Jquery World</marquee>
```

Comment: +1 for the use of the wonderful `marquee` tag. Back to your question: does the emulator have the same browser as the device?

Comment: @PeeHaa No both are different.

Comment: It is more than likely a browser issue then, you could try downloading a different browser onto the phone, to see if it makes a difference.  I wouldn't rely on features like this though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`marquee` is not a standard HTML Element! So there is no guarantee for support. Browser only support it for the sake of compatibility.

Use a jQuery plugin instead, this way you are save.

Comment: The marquee element is part of the html5 spec http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html#the-marquee-element  It is obsolete but conforming so it should still work.

Comment: @Jon Thank you for the info. I wasn't aware of it's "reintroduction".

Comment: @All : Experienced performance issue since jQuery is single threaded.

Answer (score 1):

Use This Jquery Plugin instead of marquee...

http://remysharp.com/2008/09/10/the-silky-smooth-marquee/